# How do you write a sql statement for a 'where in' clause against a composite key?

Tags: sql-server-2005, composite-key

Using MSSQL 2005 I am used to writing a statement like this:

```
delete
from myTable
where ID in (select ID from otherTable where deleted = 1)
```

How can I do this when `otherTable` has a composite primary key?

The composite key has two columns:

```
docnum float
version int
```

(My google-fu suggests using CTEs to do this however I have no experience with them.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS SQL you can do this:

```
DELETE T
FROM myTable T
INNER JOIN otherTable OT
  ON T.docnum = OT.docnum
  And T.version = OT.version
```

There's a similar syntax for updates too.

Comment: Thanks @bennor - for some reason I always shy away from using joins in delete statements and it never occured to me. I had to add my where clause as well but otherwise this was spot on.

Comment: Oops. Didn't even see the where clause... If I'm testing something like this, I usually do it in side a `BEGIN TRANSACTION ... ROLLBACK` block.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the **exists** keyword:

```
delete t1
from myTable t1
where exists (
    select * from otherTable where docnum = t1.docnum and version = t1.version
)
```